# reactjs not resolving "type" keyword in "import type {Value} from '@react-page/editor';"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, import

I'm trying to import a exported type from a module which it's documentation is in [here](https://react-page.github.io/docs/#/quick-start).

In this tutorial "import type" is used which is not resolved in my IDE.

how can I fix this????

[image: The import Code]

[image: the error]

Comment: The error here is that it is unused, not that the import didn't work. Have you used this type in your code yet?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are getting the error `, expected` you are probably using an older version of TypeScript that doesn't have `import type`.

## Fix

You must be on TypeScript 3.8 or more : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html

Comment: thank you, but how to update my type-script? i used "npm install -g type-script@latest" and now I have  typescript@4.3.4 but it didn't work...

Comment: Restart you IDE 